# given a martix, use its row/column headers to find the corresponding value

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

so this is how an example of how my data looks like in sheet to now I would like to write a macro which does:
Takes the row header (say A1 at sheet1 is value3)
Takes the column header (say A2 at sheet1 is header2)
so the value of A3 should be 0.918768 at sheet1.

I guess I can count until a certain header/value is found and address to it but is there an easy way to look up?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the `INDEX` and `MATCH` worksheet functions might be a solution.  For example, in your second screen capture, the formula in cell C1 could be something like `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$F$6,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(B1,Sheet1!$B$1:$F$1,0))`.

Comment: That is some serious excel work. I guess I was relying too much on VBA lately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Find for the value, grab it's ActiveCell and then just look for ((ActiveRow):1) and (1:(ActiveColumn)).